# MSI B550 Tomahawk + Ryzen 5800x: straight to Windows, no Access to Bios

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios, troubleshooting

**Setting**: I have a M2 drive that contains a Windows 10 x64 installation that was working just fine on an older system. This morning, that drive was dropped into a new system with

- a MSI B550 Tomahawk board (BIOS Version 7C91vA5, Release Date 2021-01-26)
- a Ryzen x5800 CPU

At first the new system would recognize the drive but would not boot. It would bring me to BIOS every time, until I changed the boot mode to CSM. Then it would boot to Windows, which I used to install updates and new drivers.

**Problem**: But now I want to get back to BIOS, but I cannot!

- Pressing "Del" during boot will cause the display to stay black and the system would not boot at all, either to Windows or BIOS; the only way out is to Reset or Power down
- Doing nothing during boot will cause the system to boot to Windows, but I don't even see the MSI logo screen / system spec screen, nor the Windows logo scene; it just straight brings me to the Windows login screen

**Attempted solution**: I have the latest BIOS downloaded to a USB drive (FAT32) and can attempt to flash the system, but I would like to hear some thoughts from the forum before I proceed.

**Question**: What is going on with my machine and how do I get back to BIOS?

Comment: Use the Advanced Startup option within Settings to boot to modify your device’s UEFI settings. The reason you had to enable CSM is because you installed Windows in Legacy mode.

Comment: @Ramhound The option isn't there if it's a BIOS/Legacy installation, as the OP already found out.

Answer (score 1):

Most foolproof, no-timing-required way:

`Settings > Update > Recovery > Advanced Startup > Restart Now`

In the blue-background screen that follows:

`Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings`

That will boot directly into the UEFI BIOS on your motherboard.

Comment: Thanks! For the 2nd step: I don’t see the UEFI Firmware Settings under Advanced option.

Comment: Weird. This is also on Windows 10 x64, latest updates in, on almost identical hardware (B550M-A Wi-Fi)... What do you see?

Comment: I see Startup Repair, Startup Settings, Command Prompt, Uninstall Updates, System Restore, and System Image Recovery.

Comment: you may try `shutdown /fw /r` the harscore variant would ve disconnect the boot drive

Comment: @yurnero Aïe, that's beyond my understanding then. Hopefully the other solutions work. Alternatively if you clear the CMOS via the battery, the motherboard might launch into the BIOS automatically. Also try booting it with no CPU and then again with the CPU in the hopes of triggering the BIOS to say "Change detected! Review settings!"

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thanks for your help. I did remove the CMOS battery!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not the optimal solution, but here's what I did:

1. Turned off PC
2. Removed the CMOS battery for a few minutes and put it back (shorting the Clear CMOS jumper did not work)

After this, I was back to the starting point of this journey: BIOS access, but no boot to Windows (boot mode was now UEFI). But I did get back to BIOS!

Next:

1. Flashed BIOS to latest firmware
2. Used a USB to clean-install Windows 10

Now the system is working as I expect it to: boot to Windows, access to BIOS if I want, and MSI + Windows logo screens.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and reinstall Windows properly from scratch in UEFI mode.